# Подгрузка AJAX "вешает" систему в WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Есть [сайт](http://dev.rere.vision/).

На нем при скролле идет подгрузка поста с помощью AJAX.

Однако, после подгрузки 20-30 постов все очень сильно начинает тормозить. Подскажите - в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покрутил сайт. А что - всё? Скроллинг вверх? Ну так понятно, страница становится очень тяжелой. Браузер затыкается. WordPress ни при чем.

Comment: да я и не грешу на вордпресс. просто интересуюсь какипе мысли могут подсказать. есть мысль держать на экране только 5 постов - текущий, два предыдущих и два следующих. но может еще есть более здравые идеи какие

Comment: Да только так, сокращать общий  размер страницы в браузере.